# Problem with FirstCup tutorial to JavaEE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am stuck here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gcqzl.html#gimvn I have `update tool` open, but there is no `javaee-firstcup-tutorial` package. (even in updates or installed components). How could I get it?

Answer (score 3):

When you open the update center goto the application image properties of the Glassfish 3 server image. In the window that opens you will see a section called "Software Sources".  check the release.javaeesdk.oracle.com.  click OK and you should be able to find the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

It is under Glassfish server installation directory (`glassfish/docs/fisrtcup`).

Answer (score 2):

In NetBeans 7.3 when you get inside

Servers,GlassFishServer 3.*,right click **View Domain Update Center** 
click on **Available Add-ons** in the left pane you can see *Javaee 6 FirstCup*.
check mark on the box and click on **Marked Install Components**.

The location of firstcup folder will be inside glassfish/docs/fisrtcup

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in NetBeans 8.0.2 and Glassfish 4.1.
Solution is same as ParaJump proposed. But look for :
**Fist Cup for Java EE 7** under Available Add-ons in GlassFish Update Tool.